# Perl Regex Help - find lines in another file

Tags: regex, perl

I want the match to occur but it's not happening.

I have an issue. I wish to find occurences of lines from one file in another.

Here's one file (@file)

```
735 1 1  
1891 1 0  
2021 1 1  
1892 2 1  
667 1 0  
802 2 1  
665 1 0  
666 1 1  
596 1 0  
3193 2 1
```

Here's the one in which I have to find above lines (@file1)

```
1521 1 0 : 1167 0 0 : 1167 2 0 : 1167 1 0 ;  
2605 1 1 ;  
2280 0 1 : 2280 2 0 : 1892 0 0 : 2280 1 0 : 2021 0 0 ;  
1892 2 1 : 667 0 1 : 667 1 0 ;  
1892 1 1 ;
```

Here's the code I wrote

```
foreach $leadline (@file1) {

  foreach $line (@file) {
    $_    = ' ' . $leadline;
    $line = ' ' . $line;
    if (m/$line/) {
      push @final, $_;
    }

  }

}
```

But I am unable to detect the lines.

`@file1` and `@file` variables store the contents of the files.

I either get no lines detected or all lines detected.

The reason I am concatenating a Space before the two lines is , that sometimes 667 1 0 can occur as the very first phrase in a given line.I am not comfortable with Regex to do that in Regex directly.

Note :- If line i and line j in first file occur as a pattern in the same line of the other file then output should be just one of the lines. Also , if a pattern 1667 1 0 is found, it shouldn't be confused with 667 1 0. Hence I added the whitespace.

I was able to achieve this goal in Python but unable to replicate it in Perl . Here's the Python snippet :-

```
for line1 in file1:
    for j in range(0,len(file0)-1):# in file0:
        if ' '+lines[j][0:len(file0[j])-1] in ' '+line1:
            i = i + 1
            print line1[0:len(line1)-1]
            break
```

Expected output is :- 
1892 2 1 : 667 0 1 : 667 1 0 ;

Comment: Are there really blank lines in your second file?

Comment: no. Sorry no blank lines.

Comment: What result are you hoping for?

Comment: If one or more patterns from 1 file are found in a Given line in the other file output that Given line.

Comment: Okay, so given this data what do you think should end up in `@final`?

Comment: 1892 2 1 : 667 0 1 : 667 1 0 ;   As, both 667 1 0 is found in it and also 1892 2 1. It doesn't matter if more than 1 is found . At least 1 should be found. Basically ,  I wish to collapse the lines in the first file,  if they occur in the same line in the other.

Comment: But `667 0 1` isn't in the first file?

Comment: 667 1 0 is. So is 1892 2 1.

Comment: So you're saying the numbers can be in any order in the line?

Comment: Yes, order doesn't matter. Treat it like a string pattern. If line i and line j in first file occur as a pattern in the same line of the other file then output should be just one of the lines. Also , if a pattern 1667 1 0 is found, it shouldn't be confused with 667 1 0. Hence I added the whitespace.

Comment: Add your expected output in your question. It would be help us to help you in better way.

Comment: Okay I think I finally understand what you need. Check my update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now think this is a solution to a different problem, but here it is anyway!

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use 5.010;

use Array::Utils 'array_diff';

open my $fh, '<', 'f1.txt' or die $!;
my @f1;
while ( <$fh> ) {
  push @f1, [split];
}

my @final;
open $fh, '<', 'f2.txt' or die $!;
while ( <$fh> ) {
  my @f2 = map [ /\d+/g ], split /:/;
  for my $f1 ( @f1 ) {
    my @matches = grep { not array_diff(@$f1, @$_) } @f2;
    push @final, map "@$_", @matches;
  }
}

say for @final;
```

**output**

```
1892 2 1
667 0 1
667 1 0
```

---

**Update**

Okay here's my second attempt! This is essentially what [`choroba` wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29943296/622310) but using `map` and with the addition of stripping all trailing whitespace on the data from the first file.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use 5.014;  # For non-destructive substitution

open my $fh, '<', 'f1.txt' or die $!;
my @f1 = map s/\s+\z//r, <$fh>;
my $re = join '|', @f1;

open $fh, '<', 'f2.txt' or die $!;
my @final = grep /\b(?:$re)\b/, <$fh>;

print for @final;
```

**output**

```
1892 2 1 : 667 0 1 : 667 1 0 ;
```

Comment: Yes, this seems more like it. But the final output should be 1 line for it. I.e line from file2 which has that. Is it one single line from file2?

Comment: OP is expecting this output: `1892 2 1 : 667 0 1 : 667 1 0 ;` means there should be only one match.

Comment: Ya , like 1892 2 1 and 667 1 0 are both present in file1 . So my Python logic was to scan for patterns from file1 in each line of file2  . If more than 0 pattern found , output line from file2 and break. Search in other lines of file2.

Comment: Ya , this one seems to work . But on the larger data set , the boundary doesn't seem to work. In larger data set , this one is also getting outputed :- 1502 0 1 : 1502 1 1 ; . Because of these two lines in file 1 ;- 501 1 1 
502 1 1

Answer (score 1):

You can create a regex by joining the lines from file1 by `|` (and applying `quotemeta` on each). `\b` should prevent matching `667` in `1667`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @search;
open my $F1, '<', 'file1' or die $!;
while (<$F1>) {
    chomp;
    push @search, quotemeta;
}

my $regex = join '|', @search;
$regex = qr/\b(?:$regex)\b/;

open my $F2, '<', 'file2' or die $!;
while (<$F2>) {
    print if /$regex/;
}
```

Comment: That's what I thought, but the OP means a match should exist even if the fields are in a different order!

Comment: That's not how I understand them.

Comment: Read their comment under the question

Comment: @Borodin: Even after reading the comments :-) Let's wait for an answer.

Comment: Ah, you're printing the lines form the *second* file that match. That's yet another way of looking at it. I assumed from the OP's code that, since they are saving lines from `@file1` in `@final` they wanted records from the first file. However it's quite possible that `@file` contains the first file data while `@file1` contains the second file

Comment: @choroba:  Your code works for me only if I do `s/\s+\z//` on the first file instead of `chomp`

Comment: Ya sorry for messing up nomenclature. @file has first file data .

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I'd do the job:

```
use Modern::Perl;
use Data::Dumper;$Data::Dumper::Indent = 1;

my @file = (
'735 1 1',
'1891 1 0',
'2021 1 1',
'1892 2 1',
'667 1 0',
'802 2 1',
'665 1 0',
'666 1 1',
'596 1 0',
'3193 2 1',
);
my @final;
while(my $line = <DATA>) {
    chomp $line;
    if (grep{$line =~ /\b$_\b/} @file) {
        push @final, $line;
    }
}
say Dumper\@final;

__DATA__
1521 1 0 : 1167 0 0 : 1167 2 0 : 1167 1 0 ;  
2605 1 1 ;  
2280 0 1 : 2280 2 0 : 1892 0 0 : 2280 1 0 : 2021 0 0 ;  
1892 2 1 : 667 0 1 : 667 1 0 ;  
1892 1 1 ;
```

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = [
  '1892 2 1 : 667 0 1 : 667 1 0 ;  '
];
```

With your files:

```
use Modern::Perl;
use Data::Dumper;$Data::Dumper::Indent = 1;

open my $fh, '<', 'file.txt' or die "unable to open 'file.txt': $!";
my @file = <$fh>;
chomp @file;

my @final;
open $fh, '<', 'file1.txt' or die "unable to open 'file1.txt': $!";
while(my $line = <$fh>) {
    chomp $line;
    if (grep{$line =~ /\b$_\b/} @file) {
        push @final, $line;
    }
}
say Dumper\@final;
```

Comment: Yes this is the expected output. Can I read inputs from files here ?

Comment: @ameyask86: Yes, of course you can read the data from the file instead of __DATA__

Comment: I could read DATA from file2 , the other one is having some issue     . open CONFIG, 'file1;



while (defined($line = <CONFIG>)) {
    push @file, $line;
}